# How to submit a SmartClient DynamicForm programmatically?

Tags: smartclient

I am trying to create a hidden form with some data, which needs to be submitted to a jsp page (which gets open in a new window), but all this would happen programatically, without user pressing submit button.

My Sample code

```
var fsquery = "abcd";
var emailId = "as@gmail.com";
var portalPsswd = "password";
var projectId = "123";
var kbUrl = "some url which will consume form post parameters";
var pv="1.2",pn="ADA";

this.kbform=isc.DynamicForm.create({
width: 300,
fields: [
{type: "hiddenitem", name: "EMAIL_ID", defaultValue:emailId },
{type: "hiddenitem", name: "PORTAL_PASSWORD", defaultValue:portalPsswd},
{type: "hiddenitem", name: "PROJECT_ID", defaultValue:projectId},
{type: "hiddenitem", name: "FSQUERY", defaultValue:fsquery},
{type: "hiddenitem", name: "PRODUCT_VERSION", defaultValue:pv},
{type: "hiddenitem", name: "PRODUCT_NAME", defaultValue:pn},
{type: "hiddenitem", name: "ORIGIN", defaultValue:"Administrator"},
{type: "submit", name: "submit", defaultValue: "submit"}
],
action: kbUrl,
target: "_blank",
method: "POST",
canSubmit: true
});

this.kbform.submit();
```

the last statement does not submit the form automatically, but if I click the submit button provided, it works perfectly as needed.

Please provide me a solution which will help me simulate "submit" type button functionality to submit the form.

You can try this sample code [here](http://smartclient.com/index.jsp#textItem) under "text.js" tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about this, but have you tried triggering the submit on a `window.onload` event? I don't think the form is available until the document is fully loaded.  I'm sorry I don't have any examples.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, even I suspect the same, somehow the `kbform.submit()` is getting called before the DynamicForm is fully loaded with values, how can I use somwthing like `window.onload` to submit the form?

Comment: Here's a bit of code which wait for the page to load then calls a timer to delay half a second, check if the form has content, then submit or loop based on the results.  That's a quick example of how I would go at it.
  
`var fSubmit = function() {
  
  if (<content present>) { 
    <submit form>
  } else { 
    fResetTimer() 
  }
}
var fResetTimer = function() {
  isc.Timer.setTimeout("fSubmit", 500)
}
window.onload=function(){ fResetTimer(); };`

Comment: This is how I solved the problem, 1st I created all the form elements without values and added it to the dialog (parent element), later I added values to it, so due to the delay in creating form items it was unable to find form to submit. thanks